# Several Complex Variables in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

After reading the very interesting quote about several complex variables in QFT:

> "The
>   axiomatization of quantum field theory consists in a number of general
>   principles, the most important of which are the following: lnvariance
>   under transformations of the inhomogeneous Lorentz groups, the
>   existence of a complete system of (physical) states with positive
>   energy, and microcausality. With this approach, physical quantities
>   are treated as the boundary values of a function $f(z)$ of several
>   complex variables that is holomorphic in some "primitive" (sometimes
>   rather complicated) domain $D$ defined by the axioms.
>
> However, in
>   contrast with the situation with a single complex variable, in the
>   space of several complex variables the following remarkable fact is
>   true: not every domain is a domain of holomorphy. Therefore, in the
>   absence of the specific form of the function $f$, the problem arises as
>   to the construction of an envelope of holomorphy $H (D)$ of the domain
>   $D$.
>
> Once the envelope $H (D)$ is constructed, we may hope in principle to
>   write the integral representation (the dispersion relationship)
>   expressing the value of an arbitrary function f that is holomorphic in
>   $D$ in terms of its values on a portion of the boundary $H (D)$. If these
>   last values are connected with experimentally observed values, the
>   integral representation obtained opens a path to the experimental
>   checking of the theory."
>
> Preface of Vladimirov's 'Methods of the Theory of Functions of Many Complex Variables'

- How is a physical quantity defined in terms of the boundary values of a SCV function?
- How does one construct the domain for such a function (e.g. in an easy example)?
- What is the envelope of holomorphy, and why do it's boundary values link to experiment!?

Knowing the specifics would be great motivation for learning SCV.

Comment: Caveat: I am not a theoretician. Having said that, I have no idea how this is supposed to relate to quantum field theory. In QFT proper we do not treat physical quantities as "several complex variables". Instead, QFT proper is a theory utilizing an infinite number of operators. Having said that, mathematicians sometimes have "funny" ways of saying the same thing in a different language, so this may be equivalent... but I would see a lot of conceptual difficulty in using this approach to read a typical high energy physics textbook or paper.

Comment: This was written by Bogoliubov in the preface talking about an axiomatic qft that he developed http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183538790 & I'm hoping for some cool intuition & motivation

Comment: OK, that would explain a couple of things. It may be worth a read, but don't be disappointed when, after many endless nights trying to fight your way trough the math you end up with the insight that axiomatic QFT is a tough nut to crack (that, to the best of my knowledge, has still not been cracked almost 40 years after this book was written). Thanks for the citation! I will try to find out what Bogoliubov had in mind (since his intuition can hardly be discounted).

Comment: Thanks, really hoping for the crux/feel of SVC in physics in an intuitive motivational way rather than gory hardcore details which I don't have time for right now (unless this motivates it! :p) If you do come across anything interesting don't be shy in sharing!

Comment: On top of page 22 of this paper http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.3/Main/icm1970.3.0021.0026.ocr.pdf it seems to say that (vacuum $\Psi_0$) expectation values of a product of operators are the boundary values of another function of several complex variables, which is at least something!

Comment: I suppose they are referring to the [Wightman axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms), that are a "minimal" set of properties that a rigorous (perturbative) QFT has to satisfy to be mathematically "acceptable". Up to the present knowledge they have been satisfied only in some QFT model in dimension 1,2 and 3 (not in 4, as one should hope...). If you are interested, I suggest you take a look at a more modern treatment of such axioms, e.g. the one presented in chap. IX.8 of Reed and Simon (see also Chapter X.7, both in volume 2).

Comment: Thanks very much, yes Reed & Simon are talking about the same things that Vladimirov mentions in his paper, sweet! Finally have a bit of a physical motivation for domains of holomorphy which is a big help! Would still love to read any comments on all this if anybody has any.